# How do you paginate a viewset using a paginator class?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

According to the documentation:

```
Pagination is only performed automatically if you're using the generic views or viewsets
```

But this doesn't seem to be the case. Here's what I have for my viewset:

```
views.py
class EntityViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Entity.objects.all()
        serializer = EntitySerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = Entity.objects.all()
        entity = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = EntitySerializer(entity)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Here's my urls

```
entity_list = views.EntityViewSet.as_view({'get':'list'})
entity_detail = views.EntityViewSet.as_view({'get':'retrieve'})
    ...
    url(r'^entity/$', entity_list, name='entity-list'),
    url(r'^entity/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', entity_detail, name='entity-detail'),
    ...
```

This is my pagination class

```
class PagePaginationWithTotalPages(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 30
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 1000

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response({
            'next': self.get_next_link(),
            'previous': self.get_previous_link(),
            'count': self.page.paginator.count,
            'total_pages': self.page.paginator.num_pages,
            'results': data
        })
```

and I set it in settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'myapp.pagination.PagePaginationWithTotalPages',
    'UNICODE_JSON': False,
}
```

Now while this works for `ListAPIView` it doesn't appear to work for my viewset. Is there a step that I'm missing?

For reference this works fine:

```
class EntitiesView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = EntitySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        parameters = get_request_params(self.request)
        qs = qs.filter(**parameters).distinct()
        return qs
```

EDIT:

Changing it to use ModelViewset appears to have done the trick

```
class EntityViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Entity.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EntitySerializer

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = self.queryset
        parameters = get_request_params(self.request)
        if 'ordering' in parameters:
            queryset = queryset.order_by(parameters['ordering'])
            del parameters['ordering']
        queryset = queryset.filter(**parameters).distinct()

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        entity = self.get_object()
        serializer = EntitySerializer(entity)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: You're overriding `viewsets.ViewSet` - it looks like you would to have to subclass a generic viewset like `GenericViewSet` or `ModelViewSet` to get the automatic pagination.

Comment: Ah I see, is there an example somewhere that I can study? @alasdair

Comment: From your code, it looks as if you could use [`ModelViewSet`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset), and set `queryset` and `serializer_class`. I don't know any other examples to link to.

Comment: Got it thanks @alasdair I think I got it down using ModelViewSet, I still think there's room for improvements but one step at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Pagination is only performed automatically if you're using the generic views or viewsets

You seem to have missed the next sentence from the documentation:

> If you're using a regular APIView, you'll need to call into the pagination API yourself to ensure you return a paginated response. See the source code for the mixins.ListModelMixin and generics.GenericAPIView classes for an example.

As pointed by the documentation, the [`ListModelMixin`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L35-L48) will show you that you didn't call the `paginate_queryset` / `get_paginated_response` and thus did bypass the pagination as well as the filtering.

As pointed in the comments, you should consider `ModelViewSet` and define the required `queryset` to get it automatically included.

Comment: Thanks! Seems like changing it to a modelviewset and modifying the code a bit did the trick. I'll update it with my final result. Out of curiosity is it possible to "disable" pagination on the api? i.e. what if some requests I don't want any pagination?

Comment: As with every DRF settings you can change it on a per view basis: set the view's pagination_class to None and it'll turn pagination off.